# Measuring distance from observations to coastline

Tags: distance, qgis-3

I am looking for a way to use a computer software to measure distances from observation points to the coast of Iceland. I have over 51,000 observations as a points layer and I have the coastline of Iceland as a polygon. Is it possible to do this calculation in QGIS and add a column (Distance) to the attributes table of the points layer?
I've found no instructional YouTube video to solve this particular exercise, though I've found many that explain how to measure distances between points. I've also found one thread where the same question was asked here last year, but the only answer was that using a different program would be the only way. The person asking that question has the same problem I do: I don't know how to code, so PostGIS is not a viable option.

Comment: Here you can find an approach on how to calculate distance to a coasline, without using postgis: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/280787/7849