# Reporting distances to polygon features along river network using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, shortest-path

I am using QGIS 3.6 on windows 10.

I am trying to work out a way of reporting on the distances to polygon features (ecological sites) located along a river network. I have extracted the shortest path along a river network, from a study area to the river's mouth, using the QNEAT3 Plugin. I have tried using v.distance to calculate the distance to ecological sites that the shortest path intersects but it appears to only provide the distance to the nearest feature and I would like distances to all features intersected.

Comment: Did you search for closes distance or other key-words? You will find some on this forum, that can inspire you to a sollution. Eg. https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/280787/7849

Comment: Thanks for getting back Pieter. I had viewed several solutions all of which appeared to indicate that the distances had to be to points. I was hoping that it may be possible to find the distances to intersections with polygons, so though I would put the question out there.

Comment: are you looking for the (minimum) distance between a linestring (river) and a polygon (site) (if they *intersect*, distance is 0)? or the distance *to the intersection* between them, *along* the linestring (from the start point)? or even the distance *along* the linestring to the point where a polygon is closest to it?

Comment: Hi @ThingamaBob, apologies for not responding earlier, didn't see you response come in. I am seeking the distance from a point on a linestring, along the linestring ('downstream' from the point) to each and every point of intersection between the linestring and a polygon layer. I would then be processing the results to find the shortest distance to each polygon along the linestring.